# Is there any case where window.location will not work in a browser? (except js turned-off)

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there is any case where window.location will not work?

I was thinking maybe some older IE browsers don't let the javascript redirect the page due to some random security restriction?

Does anyone know if there is any browser/situation where window.location = "url" will fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It should work in all JS enabled browsers.

```
window.location = 'http://example.com';
```

How are you going to use it? If it is some odd way of using it then it might not work in IE.

Comment: It actually works for me all the time. I was just wondering if there is any extremely rare edge case that I've never come across (possibly IE6 related).

Comment: @rksprst If your users are too lazy to get something better then IE, then your website shouldn't work for them.

Answer (score 3):

If the redirect is inside an iframe then the main page will not redirect. This is expected though.

Answer (score -1):

If there is an error elsewhere in your code:

```
window.location="http://www.google.com";
alert("error);
```

The missing `"` in the alert statement will prevent execution of all code by the JS engine.

Comment: This method is hacky, and instead of the alert, you could add a meta redirect tag to the head element. but both are unnecessary. window.location even works in IE.

Comment: @invisible bob I wasn't advocating its use, merely presenting a situation that satisfies the question. It could be an issue if you were including someone else's code in your page for example.